# Do I need to watch other movies from franchise to understand Spiral?

Tags: suggested-order, saw, jigsaw, spiral-from-the-book-of-saw

I have followed *Saw* franchise long ago (decade kind of) and didn't even check *Jigsaw* yet and wanted to catch *Spiral: From the Book of Saw* but can I understand it?

Is this film able to be understandable solo or do I need to see Jigsaw? Or any other previous film?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an enormous amount of effort and thought put into the making of Spiral to have it NOT be Saw IX. A lot of the choices made are actually discussed throughout the [Spiral wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_(2021_film)).

In addition, Spiral was also not meant to be a complete reboot. There still may be a Saw 9, and may also be a sequel to Spiral.

Finally, it also is not a reimagination. It is simply a similar movie where the antagonist is a Jigsaw copycat, and which utilizes the theme of traps giving the victims the choice of death versus voluntary dismemberment/disfigurement/disablement.

In my opinion, as a long time Saw franchise 'fan', Spiral is quite able to be appreciated as a stand-alone movie, however a viewer would better understand the traps if one or two of the original series were previously viewed. It is definitely not a requirement to view all previous 8 movies in the franchise to understand Spiral.

If, as you say, you've seen previous movies in the series, you are perfect as a viewer of this new one. You'll 'get' the concept of the traps and not be completely lost in the why of things.